# Pattern matching Nil with alternative

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I expect this code to print "a", but it prints "b". Why ?

```
Nil match {
  case Nil | _ if 1 > 1 => println("a")
  case x => println("b")
}
```

But this code prints "a" as expected

```
Nil match {
  case Nil => println("a")
  case x => println("b")
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `|` is part of the value match expression, and the `if` is an entirely separate thing. I suspect you interpret that line as `case (Nil) | (_ if 1 > 1)` but it's actually more like `case (Nil | _) if 1 > 1`.

So the `if 1 > 1` part is being checked if the matched value is `Nil` or anything (`_`), causing that case to never be matched.